# Calculate screen size in a sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are tonnes of tutorials / examples of making a header stick on scroll for fixed height headers. However, I am working on a one page website and the initial section is a full screen image. The user then scrolls down to reveal the header and other content areas.

So my question is, how can I change my code to take into account the viewport / screen size - rather than use a fixed header size?

My existing code is:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= 65) {
        $(".main").addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $(".main").removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the height of the window instead of a fixed value (since you're talking about a full screen image, I'm guessing its height is equal to the window height):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (scroll >= $(window).height()) {
        $(".main").addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $(".main").removeClass("sticky");
    }
});
```

You could also get the height of the first section, if it's smaller than the window

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better solution, but here's my solution :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= $(window).height()*0.2) { //0.2 for 20% of the viewport height, you can change this value if you need to
    $(".main").addClass("sticky");
} else {
    $(".main").removeClass("sticky");
}
});
```

I just used `$(window).height()` to get the viewport height.